# How to target different v-on:click events with same method in Vue component (show/hide different elements)

Tags: events, vue.js, onclick

I have a method called `toggleShow`.
I'm calling it from 2 different elements, but i need `toggleShow` to toggle the `v-if` value of the element that called it. what is the cleanest way it can be done in vue.js?

[CodeSandbox of my attempt](https://codesandbox.io/embed/j4n54o6r13)

```html
<template>
    <div @click="toggleShow">
      <button v-if="!isShowing">View Hidden Box 1</button>
      <div v-if="isShowing">
        <button>Close Hidden Box 1</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div @click="toggleShow">
      <button v-if="!isShowing">View Hidden Box 2</button>
      <div v-if="isShowing">
        <button>Close Hidden Box 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      isShowing: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleShow() {
      this.isShowing = !this.isShowing;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to make an array of boxes with their own instance of isShowing in your data object. Then render the boxes in a v-for loop. toggleShow accepts the index of the box clicked.

```js
new Vue( {
 el: '#app',
  data: {
    boxes: [
       { isShowing: false },
        { isShowing: false },
      ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggleShow(i) {
      this.boxes[i].isShowing = !this.boxes[i].isShowing;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 75px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.shade {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #07070771;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="hello container" id="app">
  <div v-for="(box, index) in boxes" class="box" @click="toggleShow(index)">
    <button v-if="!box.isShowing">View {{ index + 1 }}</button>
        <div class="shade" v-if="box.isShowing">
          <button>Close {{ index + 1 }}</button>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```